# Server-Client program blocks at Input

Tags: java

So I have this Server-Client and my program is blocking in the line where I have "in" when im trying to conect the client to the server

```
private void connections(String s,int port) throws IOException{

    socket = new Socket(s,port);

    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());     
}
```

Not that matter but I have this in a thread

Comment: could you please share the whole stacktrace if you are getting an exception?

Comment: not getting an exception, when I debbug it just stops at that line

Comment: The server you are trying to connect (via the line "new Socket(s,port)" ), is that server up and you have access to it (no firewall blocking or anything like that?). I believe, you will get a connection timeout/refused if you wait for sometime...

Comment: @N0000B actually tried what you said for about 15 minutes and nothing happened, the program was just frozen. And yes everytime I run my main I have the serversocket and socket created

Comment: So you are creating a server socket and client in same thread/program?

Comment: I create the server socket in main then have a thread creating the client socket

Comment: Literally inverted places and it started to work